# how to run nodejs flatiron/director example

Tags: node.js, flatiron.js

I tried to run the https://github.com/flatiron/director#client-side example to get familiar with director.js.

I am not able to setup the **flatiron** module on the client-side.

In my html page (say, `<my_project>/page.html`) I replaced the location of `director.js` with 
a location of its counterpart from my project:

`<my_project>/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director.js`

Upon loading the `<my_project>/page.html` page in the browser 
I got errors: export and Router not defined.

First idea: After all, on the browser side there is no nodejs...

Ok, I thought that browserify could help me with it.
I generated a single 'browser-side' bundle (was it necessary?):

```
my_project> node node_modules/browserify/bin/cli.js node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib director.js -o cs_director.js
```

and I used it in the line: `<script src="cs_director.js"></script>`

The problem is that the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Router is not defined
(anonymous function)
```

still appears so I guess the whole example will not work.

I am new to node/js and I am not sure if it makes sens what I have done in my case described above...
Does anybody how to solve it?

Or generally, how to use 'isomorphic' stuff on a browser-side?
The html examples on Github just refer to the same .js files 
as server-side examples ...

Can you recommend any tutorials, examples?

Thanks,
-gvlax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a browser-specific build of `director` [here](https://github.com/flatiron/director/tree/master/build) which has all of the server code stripped away.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks DeadDEnD,

Now it works like a charm!

I have no idea how I could missed that info in readme ... I read the manual first, I swear:-)

Here is my sample code:

```
  <!html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script src="director-1.0.7.min.js"></script>

            <script>

        var author = function () { console.log("author called.");},
            books = function () { console.log("books called."); },
            viewBook = function(bookId) { console.log("viewBook called."); };

        var routes = {
          '/author': author,
          '/books': [books, function() { console.log("anonymous fun called."); }],
          '/books/view/:bookId': viewBook
        };

        var router = Router(routes);
        router.init();

      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Click <a href="#/books">me</a> to call two functions at a time. 
    </body>
  </html>
```

--gvlax